# Atlassian Bamboo SSH task for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssh, bamboo, openssh

I have several task in my plan. The latest task is running a spring boot application war on a remote Windows Server machine over ssh to start up rest web service.

The spring boot war is starting successfully and the logs could be seen also in Bamboo. However this task never ends because it is always printing the output. I couldn't do a "fire and forget ssh task". I tried below SSH commands in SSH Task :

1) Doesn't work :

`javaw -jar C:\dev\jar\myspringbootapp.war`

2) Works but the task never ends :

```
cmd /C javaw -jar C:\dev\jar\myspringbootapp.war
```

3) Works but the task never ends :

i put the command in a batch file. SSH command is this:

```
cmd /C C:/dev/ftp/runjava.bat
```

And the content of the batch file is :

```
@echo off

javaw -jar C:\dev\jar\myspringbootapp.war &
```

Comment: have you tried `start javaw -jar C:\dev\jar\myspringbootapp.war &` in the batch file? or even `call`

Comment: Yeah i have also tried this

Comment: and? what was the result? window stayed open?

Comment: why not just call it from a vbs hide script, it will never be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve the problem.

First i set the SSH command as this:

```
powershell.exe -InputFormat None -F "C:/dev/ftp/script3.ps1" | out-null
```

The "`| out-null`" is the required parameter.

Than i write the below command in the script3.ps1:

```
javaw -jar C:\dev\jar\my-application.war
```